# Variable length array feature of C language not working in Visual Studio

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic-arrays

I'm trying to use the "[Variable length array feature of C language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member) refered [in this link](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/variable-length-arrays-in-c-and-c/).

The live working example of this C feature is [HERE](http://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/JQdpYU).

```
void fun(int n)
{
    int arr[n];
    arr[0] = 30;
    printf("%d", arr[0]);
}

int main()
{
    fun(6);
}
```

However, if i copy the same code to a VS2013 project, it complains

```
1>pureC.c(11): error C2057: expected constant expression
1>pureC.c(11): error C2466: cannot allocate an array of constant size 0
1>pureC.c(11): error C2133: 'arr' : unknown size
```

**Is it something to do with compiler setting or how do i fix this issue ?**

Comment: VS2013 uses a C++ compiler to compile source code, and C != C++.

Comment: This is not a flexible array member. It's a variable length array.

Comment: @EOF: ok thanks for correction. Edited the name of thi sfeature

Comment: But you're still linking to the same (inappropriate) site.

Comment: The Microsoft C compiler provided with Visual Studio offers only partial support of C99 and later features, and one of the things missing is VLAs.  If you really want to use VLAs in your code, you'll have to use a different compiler (such as gcc in the MinGW or Cygwin envrionments).

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5471dc8s.aspx